# Elasticsearch OPERATOR for Nested queries

Tags: json, elasticsearch, operator-keyword, nested-attributes

I have a relatively simple construction in my index. A customer has it`s own properties and he has his identity, emails and phones as nested attributes. So far all my queries work ok, when i query the nested objects. I am developing something like a global search, that allows the user to type in any information and i present him the corresponding customer. For this purpose i'm iterating over all the nested properties that i have(since i don't know what exactly is he searching for). My query looks like this:

```
{
"sort": ["_score"],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "nested": {
                "path": "identity",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "my search",
                                "fields": "identity.*"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "nested": {
                "path": "phones",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "my search",
                                "fields": "phones.*"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

However it seems that when you have multiple nested queries the "AND" operator is applied, thus i'm not getting the correct information. If i search over only one nested object i get the correct results always. I tried putting the "operator" => "or" almost everywhere, but to no effect, and the documentation does not say much about this case(or at least i cannot find anything). What am i missing?

Comment: You can also remove the "sort": ["_score"], this is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the "must" with "should" to get the or behavior, See more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Comment: Hmm, that seems to really add a logical 'or', to the query, however it breaks a lot of the other cases . For example if a have 2 customers(john and dom) and i search for john i get john AND dom as results. That happens if a change the `must` with `should`

Comment: Can you share a sample of 2 documents? one with john and one with dom?

Comment: It seems that i managed to get the expected behaviour, but i also needed to specify the `minimum_should_match` param. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a sample:

```
{
"uid": "uid",
"oid": "oid",
"tags": ["VIP"],
"identity": {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "567901d6ab265d4cf7000001"
    },
    "first": "John",
    "gender": "male",
    "last": "",
    "middle": "",
    "prefix": "",
    "suffix": ""
},
"phones": [{
    "_id": "23232323-642f-4ce1-ab1b-542bbd1468ea",
    "created_at": null,
    "name": "mobile",
    "updated_at": null,
    "value": "987654321"
}],
"emails": [{
    "_id": "12121212-642f-4ce1-ab1b-542bbd1468ea",
    "created_at": null,
    "name": "home",
    "updated_at": null,
    "value": "john@john.com"
}]
}

{
"uid": "uid",
"oid": "oid",
"tags": ["VIP"],
"identity": {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "567901d6ab265d4cf7000001"
    },
    "first": "Dom",
    "gender": "male",
    "last": "",
    "middle": "",
    "prefix": "",
    "suffix": ""
},
"phones": [{
    "_id": "23232323-642f-4ce1-ab1b-542bbd1468ea",
    "created_at": null,
    "name": "mobile",
    "updated_at": null,
    "value": "987654321"
}],
"emails": [{
    "_id": "12121212-642f-4ce1-ab1b-542bbd1468ea",
    "created_at": null,
    "name": "home",
    "updated_at": null,
    "value": "dom@dom.com"
}]
}
```

So if i use the `must` clause and i do a search for john/dom i'm not getting any results(remember, i'm searching over all nested documents and the phones do not contain any 'john/dom', if i search only over identity/emails i will get the right result, because emails also contain the name).

If i switch to `should` clause and i do the same query i'm getting back both john and dom.

The final query looks like this:

```
{
"_source": ["oid", "uid"],
"sort": ["_score"],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "nested": {
                "path": "identity",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "john",
                                "operator": "and",
                                "fields": ["identity.*"],
                                "type": "cross_fields",
                                "tie_breaker": 1.0
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "nested": {
                "path": "emails",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "john",
                                "operator": "and",
                                "fields": ["emails.*"],
                                "type": "cross_fields",
                                "tie_breaker": 1.0
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "nested": {
                "path": "phones",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "john",
                                "operator": "and",
                                "fields": ["phones.*"],
                                "type": "cross_fields",
                                "tie_breaker": 1.0
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }],
        "filter": [{
            "term": {
                "oid": "oid"
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```